# Papéis no Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Bom, não encontrei em algum outro post, se existir srry :)
enfim,

tenho a seguinte config

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the index page
        .when('/index', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/index.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

});
```

só que queria trabalhar com views diferentes, para usuários diferentes, na mesma rota.

Por exemplo, tenho dois usuários, o usuário X que é adm e o usuário Y que é um usuário comum, então quando ambos acessarem a rota '/index' terão a mesma view.

Porém quando acessarem a rota '/home' queria que um template diferente fosse mostrado para cada um. Como posso fazer isso?

Aceito todo tipo de ajuda. VALEEU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar diretivas e inseri-las no seu home.html

Na controller `aboutController` voce captura os dados da sessão, verifica se o usuario esta logado e coloca a informação no `$scope.usuario`. Você poderá passá-lo para a diretiva e usar o objeto `usuario` lá.

home.html

```
<div ng-if="usuario.privilegio == 'guest'">
<diretiva-para-guest usuario=usuario></diretiva-para-guest>
</div>

<div ng-if="usuario.privilegio == 'admin'">
<diretiva-para-admin usuario=usuario></diretiva-para-admin>
</div>
```

Na diretiva você chama os HTMLs para cada e passa os dados como queira...

diretiva-guest.js

```
app.directive('diretivaParaGuest', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
         scope: {
            usuario: '='

        },
        templateUrl: "home-guest.html",
        controller: function($scope){


          $scope.ola = "Hello Usuario" + $scope.usuario.nome;

         },
        controllerAs: 'guestController'
    };
});
```

diretiva-admin.js

```
app.directive('diretivaParaAdmin', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
        usuario: '='

    },
        templateUrl: "home-admin.html",
        controller: function($scope){


          $scope.ola = "Hello Usuario" + $scope.usuario.nome;

         },
        controllerAs: 'adminController'
    };
});
```

Comment: Olha, fez muito sentido pra mim. kkkk Obrigado!